# Using Minkowski's inequality in a proof

Tags: asymptotics

Hi: I'm reading a proof in Halbert White's "asymptotic theory for econometricians" and I don't understand one of the steps. The theorem supposes the following:

$E(X^2_{thi})^{1+\delta} < \triangle < \infty$ for some $\delta > 0 $ and all $h = 1, \ldots p, ~i = 1, \ldots k$, and all $t$.

Then, it starts off the proof by saying the following:

By Minkowski's inequality:

$$E \left|\sum_{h=1}^{p} X_{thi} X_{thj}\right|^{1+\delta} \le \left|\sum_{h=1}^{p} (E|X_{thi} X_{thj}| ^{(1+\delta)})^\left(\frac{1}{1+\delta}\right)\right| ^{1+\delta}.$$

Can someone show or explain how the relation above is obtained from A) the stated assumption and B) Minkowski's inequality ( or any other inequality in case it's a typo and it's using some other inequality ). The rest of the proof makes sense so no need to state the rest.

Minkowski's inequality is :

Let $q \ge 1$. If $E(|Y|^q) < \infty $ and  $E(|Z|^q) < \infty $, then

$$\left(E|Y + Z|^{q}\right)^\left(\frac{1}{q}\right) \le E(|Y|^q)^\left(\frac{1}{q}\right) + E(|Z|^q)^\left(\frac{1}{q}\right).$$

Comment: Let $q=1+\delta$ and raise both sides of Minkowski's Inequality to the $q$ power.

Comment: @whuber. I get that I think. even though Y and Z are just two terms, they can represent two  $X_{thi} X_{thj}$ terms. and then, by induction, MI works for any number of terms in the sum.  if that's right,  can I check what you said and make it an actual answer. great stuff.

Comment: Yes, the induction is correct.  It's easy, too, because this inequality is just the triangle inequality: it provides the norm for Banach spaces.  Thus, the induction is carried out in exactly the same way you would do for any metric space.  It amounts to proving the following: "If it is never any shorter to stop at an intermediate point in traveling (along geodesics) from any point $A$ to any other point $B$, then it is never any shorter to stop at a finite number of intermediate points, either."

Comment: beautifully explained.  I will check your comment as an answer but I don't know how to make it into an answer.

Comment: @mlofton: You can self-answer! just acknowledge whuber in the answer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is from @whuber.

Let $q=1+\delta$ and raise both sides of Minkowski's Inequality to the q power.

The inequality is just the triangle inequality: it provides the norm for Banach spaces. Thus, the induction is carried out in exactly the same way you would do for any metric space. It amounts to proving the following: "If it is never any shorter to stop at an intermediate point in traveling (along geodesics) from any point A to any other point B, then it is never any shorter to stop at a finite number of intermediate points, either."